# How to listen properly with HttpListener

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient, httplistener

I've been writing a server for an app of mine. Due to suggestions, I decided to use `HttpListener` to listen for incoming connections in an `async` method. My current code is as following:

```
        public static async void StartServerAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client.. ");
                var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
// ReSharper disable once CSharpWarnings::CS4014
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessClient(context));
            }
            listener.Close();
        }
```

This method is started with this:

```
public static void ServerBoot()
{
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:1000/");
    listener.Start();
    StartServerAsync();
}
```

The `ProcessClient()` method is as following:

```
private static void ProcessClient(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        string response;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
        {
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Got command: {0}", response);
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading string, closing..");
        return;
    }
}
```

Right now it's only supposed to get the string posted. However, when I run the client with this code:

```
                Console.WriteLine(" -- Bagrut Client -- ");
                Console.Write("Enter IP of server to connect to: ");
// ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                var ip = Console.ReadLine();
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                var response = client.UploadString(ip, "query");
                Console.WriteLine("Type of response is {0}", response);
```

the server does not do anything. As you can see in `ProcessClient()`, and in the server loop itself, it should at least say *something* when a client connects. However, when the code is run, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: new code:

```
        public static void ServerBoot()
        {
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:1337/");
            listener.Start();
            StartServerAsync(listener).ContinueWith(task => { });
        }
        private static void ProcessClient(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = context.Request;
                string response;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
                {
                    response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Got command: {0}", response);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading string, closing..");
                return;
            }
        }
        private static async Task StartServerAsync(HttpListener listener)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client.. ");
                var context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
// ReSharper disable once CSharpWarnings::CS4014
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartServerAsync(listener));
                ProcessClient(context);
                await StartServerAsync(listener);
            }
            listener.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I've seen code that includes a wait handle of some sort before the call to StartNew, that gets reset in code like ProcessClient so that the next GetContextAsync won't occur until after the Request is retrieved.  But, I haven't see anything that proves that's required...

Comment: Does it not even print "Waiting for client?" Can you post a short but *complete* client/server pair for us to try?

Comment: It does not. I put the source here:  http://pastebin.com/5iNGyQSn

Comment: Also, I tried doing the server on port 80, but it makes no difference.

Comment: What happens if you change `void StartServerAsync` to `Task StartServerAsync` and `StartServerAsync()` to `StartServerAsync().Wait()`? There could be many things wrong here, you need to give us a bit more to work with...

Comment: @khelland  Never mind, it still doesn't work. I updated the OP to show my new code. It says "Server started!" now!